# how to get files from host machine to vagrant VM (MAC OS)

Tags: vagrant

I haven't used vagrant for a while so I am racking my brains out on this one.

I know for a fact that one way to "exchange files" between the host machine and the vagrant VM is to copy any file you need into the host machine's vagrant folder that holds the Vagrantfile - the SAME folder where  you run 'vagrant up' and 'vagrant ssh' to get connected to the /home/vagrant folder (indicating that you have entered the vagrant vm).  However, when I get into the vagrant vm folder /home/vagrant I do not the files that I added in the host machine's vagrant folder.

I tried another approach by going in the vagrant vm's default folder /home/vagrant and run 'touch hello.txt'.   Then I checked the host machine's vagrant folder using Finder and nope, I don't see hello.txt file either.

Appreciate any helpful inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it...

Inside the `Vagrantfile` file, look for the following config setting:

> config.vm.synced_folder

And mine's actually set as:

> config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"

When I gone back to check the `/vagrant` (NOT `/home/vagrant`) folder in my vagrant vm, there i found the files that I placed in my host machine's vagrant folder.

Although I wonder what the "." means - but in the meantime, I'm happy I found what I needed :)